# Template deduction of pointer-to-array-member's size

Tags: c++, templates

Sometimes it is convenient for a template function to deduce the size of a constant array when the array is passed by reference.

```
template <unsigned N>
void foo (int (&arg) [N]);

int data [3];

foo (data); // deduces N=3
```

Now I want to perform this deduction on a pointer to an array member. This should give you the idea

```
struct X
{
    int inner_data_1 [3];
    int inner_data_2 [4];
};

template <typename T, unsigned N>
void bar (int T ::* (& arg1) [N], int (& arg2) [N])
{
    // In the example below:
    //    arg1 should be a pointer to X::inner_data_X
    //    arg2[i] should be the value of outer_data_X[i]
    // and ultimately I want a pointer to X::inner_data_X[i]
}

int main ()
{
    X x;

    int outer_data_1 [3];
    int outer_data_2 [4];

    bar (& X::inner_data_1, outer_data_1);
    bar (& X::inner_data_2, outer_data_2);

    // This should create a compile error because N is mismatched
    //bar (& X::inner_data_1, outer_data_2);
}
```

I'm not expressing this correctly, I think the type of arg1 in bar is "array[N] of pointer-to-member-of-T" but what I want is "pointer to member-of-array[N]-of-T"

Can I do this?

If I can, it seems like `arg1[N]` wouldn't be valid so I'd have to write something like

```
T * object;
auto ptr_to_ith_member = & ((object->*arg1)[i]);
```

Which is what I want to correlate with `arg2[i]` in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation is rather straight forward:

```
template <typename T, typename S, int Size>
void bar(T (S::*)[Size], T (&)[Size])
{
}
```

This function deduces the type `T` of the array elements, the enclosing type `S`, and the `Size` of a pointer to a member array.

Comment: Seems to work in the simple test code, thanks. So this is passing arg1 by value rather than by reference, and that's the only change? I suppose that's fine, but just out of curiosity, what would a *reference* to a pointer to a member of an array of N look like? :-)

Comment: You want to pass a member pointer by reference? Well, that would look something like this: `T (S::*&)[Size]`. You'd use it with an expression like that `int (foo::*ref)[4] = &foo::iarray; bar(ref, array);`. You can't just use `&foo::iarray` because that would be temporary member pointer which can't be bound to a non-`const` reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want pointer to member array, the syntax would be:

```
template <typename T, unsigned N>
void bar (int (T::*arg1) [N], int (& arg2) [N])
```

Comment: I get `no matching function for call to ‘bar(int (X::*)[3], int [3])’` which is missing references in the argument types.

Comment: @spraff: Are you sure [you typed everything correctly?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=538516a93ec7a562f301418ca86157a8-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51).

Comment: I didn't post my exact code, I tidied it up by, for example, removing a declaration of `X::X()` which would remove the unnused-variable error. I only wanted to post enough to indicate what I'm attempting, not a full program.